# Get a part of a css class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I currently have a CSS class called `widget_remove_friendsWidget` but also a CSS class `widget_remove_profileWidget`

Now, I'm trying to get the widget name from the CSS class using jQuery, so for example:

When I have the CSS class `widget_remove_friendsWidget`, I don't want to get the full CSS class but only the part after `widget_remove_` so that would be `friendsWidget` instead of `widget_remove_friendsWidget`

How can I do this?

Comment: split it into 2 classes `widget_remove` and `friendsWidget` / `profileWidget`

Comment: Does your element have any more classes or just these ?

Comment: There are like 5 sorts of those

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `replace()` function to get rid of the class prefix:

```
var className = $('.widget_remove_profileWidget').attr('class').replace('widget_remove_', '');
```

In case there are more than one classes in the same element:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#click', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var classArr = that.attr('class').split(' ');
  var target = $('#className');
  for (i in classArr) {
    var item = classArr[i];
    if (item.indexOf('prefix_') != -1) {
      var name = item.replace('prefix_', '');
    }
  }
  target.html(name);
})
```

```css
#click {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#className {
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="click" class="prefix_nameOne anotherClass">click</span>
<span id="className"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try thid will select all element  class value  contain friendsWidget

```
$('[class~=friendsWidget]')
```

Comment: No, I don't think that's a good idea because I also have classes like widget_profileWidget_header etc, but I already solved it by using @kapantzak 's answer